# Clojure - check if delay's nth element was realized

Tags: concurrency, clojure, functional-programming

I am trying to do an exercise from Chapter 3 from the excellent book "Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks" by Paul Butcher. The relevant code (provided in the book) looks like this:

```
  (ns server.core
  (:require [server.sentences   :refer [strings->sentences]]
            [server.charset     :refer [wrap-charset]]
            [compojure.core     :refer :all]
            [compojure.handler  :refer [api]]
            [ring.util.response :refer [charset response]]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :refer [run-jetty]]
            [clj-http.client    :as client]))

(def snippets (repeatedly promise))

// another service handling translations - up and running OK
(def translator "http://localhost:3001/translate")

(defn translate [text]
  (future
    (:body (client/post translator {:body text}))))

// strings->sentences simply splits and joins the snippets into full sentences
// e.g. ("full. not", "full. sentence.") will be mapped to ("full.", "not full.", "sentence.")
(def translations
  (delay
    (map translate (strings->sentences (map deref snippets)))))

(defn accept-snippet [n text]
  (deliver (nth snippets n) text))

(defn get-translation [n] 
  @(nth @translations n))

(defroutes app-routes
  (PUT "/snippet/:n" [n :as {:keys [body]}]
    (accept-snippet (Integer. n) (slurp body))
    (response "OK"))
  (GET "/translation/:n" [n] 
    (response (get-translation (Integer. n)))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (run-jetty (wrap-charset (api app-routes)) {:port 3000}))
```

The `translations` value is a `delay` which maps `snippets` to full sentences and ultimately their translations.
The objective is to change the behaviour of the `/translation` endpoint so that it doesn't block when the required translation is not yet available but returns a status 409 instead.

My idea was to "peek" at `translations` to check if the wanted element was `realized`. I tried to do it this way:

```
 (defn translation-realized? [n]
  (if 
    (and 
      (realized? translations) 
      (realized? (nth @translations n)))
    true
    false)) 

...

    (GET "/translation/:n" [n]
       (if (translation-realized? n)
         ((println "found translation") (response (get-translation (Integer. n))))
         {:status 409
            :body   "Not translated yet."})))
```

When I run the test client (which sends some snippets to be mapped and translated and then recovers translations) it seems to be blocked when trying to recover the first translation. When additionally I run a second one it gets 409 no matter which translation it's trying to get. Additionally, I set up some logging in the external service (the one providing translations) and it doesn't receive any requests.

I suppose that my solution isn't very idiomatic functional programming, so I have two questions:

- Why doesn't it work? I assumed that any `deref` applied to `translations` will block when there's nothing mapped yet. Thus my first predicate `(realized? translations)`. But then the first client should not be blocked.
- What's the idiomatic way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I may have misstated the the problem.

If I understand correctly, snippets can arrive in any order and translations can be requested in any order. In the original code, if a client requests for a translation that is not yet present it will block. The goal is to respond with 409 immediately.

I achieved some improvement by changing `translations` to be a `future` instead of a `delay` and leaving only the second clause in `translation-realized?` but the behaviour is still incorrect. First request for a translation always returns a 409, even if the required snippets had been delivered beforehand. Subsequent requests for the same translation return correct responses.

Comment: I haven’t studied your code in detail, but it looks like this piece of Clojure fundamentals could be relevant here: [Clojure Don’ts: Lazy Effects](https://stuartsierra.com/2015/08/25/clojure-donts-lazy-effects).

Comment: First, I would suggest trying to get this to work in the REPL first, without bothering with the HTTP stuff, to try to isolate the problem. The way you've layered promises, futures and delays is not idiomatic and likely the source of your problems here. Don't forget that `snippets` is also going to be a lazy sequence, which means that the `delay` might just return the head of the unresolved sequence. And since `delay` only ever returns one value, you might only get the first part of that sequence.

Comment: It can help to clarify that the code is actually completely from the book (page 80 in my copy) and that the task is one exercise from the "Day 3 Self Study" section.

Comment: Is this correct?  Do you miss a `do` in `((println "found translation") (response (get-translation (Integer. n))))`?

Comment: @JurajMartinka That is correct! Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @rmcv Sorry, didn't work...

Comment: @skillet-thief You're right - the problem should be simplified, but as JurajMartinka mentioned this is an example from a book. I'm not sure about your point on delay though. Since it's body is a collection I should either block until any element appears or return the whole collection. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: @DCzo - your `((println "found translation") (...))` will throw exception.  You have to change it to  `(do (println "found translation") (...))`

Comment: @rmcv Sorry, but this doesn't help. The behaviour is the same regardless of whether I use `do` or not. And also I don't this it's the root of the problem.

Comment: Your client call is blocked because `(map deref snippets)` in `get-translation` is waiting for the snippets in front of the nth element to be delivered.  You have to call get-translation in order (starting with 0) to avoid this and then you will hit the missing `do` issue.

Comment: @rmcv I think I didn't give enough background for the problem so I edited the question. The requests may come in arbitrary order. Also removing the prints didn't help, which makes me think, this is not related to the cause.